# catch last value by subscribing on statusChanges

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a simple reactive form and I'm subscribing to the `statusChanges` event:

```
config.test = config.cellEditingFormGroup.statusChanges
      .pipe()
      .subscribe((value) => {
        console.log(value);
      });
```

Later in the code, if the user presses any key, the form field is set to `undefined` and therefore the form status gets invalid and after that the pressed key appears in the form field and the form status gets valid. Short: on the first keystroke, the above code consoles `invalid`, then `valid`. But I need only `valid`.

Now, I want to catch the last emitted value. But if I change the code like this:

```
config.test = config.cellEditingFormGroup.statusChanges
      .pipe(last())
      .subscribe((value) => {
        console.log(value);
      });
```

I don't get anything, if I press any key.

So, the question is, how to catch the last emitted value?

Comment: `last()` emits only when the Observable completes which never happens with `statusChanges`. You maybe want to use `pairwise()` and `filter()` to check when value changes from `invalid` to `valid`.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [`debounce`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/debounce), [`throttle`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/throttle) or [`audit`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/audit) ?

Comment: `debounceTime(1)` solved the issue.

Comment: You can combine debounceTime and throttle to wait for the emitted data on observable if the user does not yet have activity on the input form.